# Is there an AVX, AVX2, or AVX512 function like _mm256_mulhi_epu16, but for 8-bit?

Tags: avx, avx2, avx512

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3967,3970&text=_mm256_mulhi_epu16

Essentially, what i need is "_mm256_mulhi_epu8" (which do not exist as it seems), which would

"Multiply the packed unsigned 8-bit integers in a and b, producing intermediate 16-bit integers, and store the high 8 bits of the intermediate integers in dst."

Is there a way to do that with any of the 256-bit or 512-bit instruction sets on x86?

Comment: Not really, you'll just have to unpack to 16 bits, use e.g. [`_mm256_mulhi_epu16 `](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_mulhi_epu16&expand=3954,3970,3970,3970), and then pack to 8 bits.

Comment: Instead of unpacking it is sometimes better to mask (or shift) away one half before `_mm256_mulhi_epu16 ` and blend together the upper and lower results. In some special cases, you could also exploit [`[v]pmaddubsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddubsw)

Comment: @PaulR thanks! it works, and i am getting correct 16-bit results, but can't see a good way to pack it back to 8-bit...

Comment: `_mm256_packs_epi16` / `_mm512_packs_epi16` pack from 16 bit to 8 bit